# Needed Automation process for data insert for multiple tables at a time using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Any idea how to insert the data from one table to another table no manual insert ,Any automation with using pyspark?

I tried using pyspark created dataframe ,in that data frame I created one table which is having the 3 properties,which will call the main table and backup table and Spark.sql(insert overwrite maintable select *from back up)
But this is not working ,Any alternative easy solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.